# How to trigger javascript function after Find by name

Tags: javascript

I'm stuck with the Javascript issue with the trigger function after finding that by name,

Here is my code, Need to trigger this function if exists

```
if (this.ui.find('functionName'))
{
    this.ui.find('functionName').trigger('click');
}
```

Tried to trigger the function name as  'functionName', tried like this but know it's not the correct way, Please help me to resolve this

Comment: Add tags for the libraries you're using. A good question should include minimal code to reproduce the issue, what you expect to happen and what actually happens plus any error or warning messages.

Comment: just using javascript and getting HTML from the database and while loading the page I just trying to execute the function inside that. The HTML is getting this.ui

Comment: Perhaps you're confusing jQuery's `element.trigger(event)` method with what's available in vanilla Javascript. Also, you seem to want to trigger a click event on a function. If your function exists, why not simply call it?